# Laravel Artisan Migrate Not Creating Tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I have followed the tutorial ([here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick)) to setup my app. Then I tried to replicate the steps to create more tables, so I ran a few command in the terminal like:

```
php artisan migrate:make create_generalUserInfo_table
```

Then in the create_generalUserInfo_table file I added:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateGeneralUserInfoTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('generalUserInfo', function($table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('firstname', 100);
            $table->string('lastname', 100);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('generalUserInfo');
    }

}
```

Then Back to terminal I ran:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

It is adding the migrants but the tables are not being create in mysql. the Users table from the initial tutorial was created

```
Migrated: 2015_01_28_055418_create_users_table
Migrated: 2015_01_28_213951_create_imprints_table
Migrated: 2015_01_28_214023_create_generalUserInfo_table
Migrated: 2015_01_28_214103_create_roles_table
Migrated: 2015_01_28_214114_create_role_user_table
Migrated: 2015_01_28_214146_create_comments_table
Migrated: 2015_01_28_214159_create_books_table
```

Comment: Just run php artisan migrate, the migrate:refresh is to do a rollback http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations#rolling-back-migrations

Comment: It says nothing to migrate

Comment: the migrate command is to run all the outstanding migrations http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations#running-migrations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change this line:

```
Schema::create('generalUserInfo', function($table){
```

to

```
Schema::create('generalUserInfo', function(Blueprint $table){
```

and run the migration command like this:

```
php artisan migrate
```

You should also make sure that

- your migration table doesn't have those tables inserted as migrated
- your database credentials are correct and point to the correct DB

Comment: When I make the changes and then run php artisan migrate it says "Nothing to migrate", I tried migrate:refresh as well

Comment: Then your migration files are either not in the migration folder of your laravel installation or your migration table has those tables entered as migrated.

Comment: btw, you are deleting and remigrating your tables with migrate:refresh, so I wouldn't do this if you have any data stored...

Comment: so in mysql I deleted all of the migrations and dropped the users table, then ran the migrate command again. Still only the users table was created but all of the other files were added to migrations table. Does the above create file look wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does it throw any errors? Can you please check your laravel log (storage/logs/laravel.log). I can't see any errors else @AlexPelletier

Comment: No errors in the log file. I don't understand why the users table is created but the other tables aren't.

Comment: It's really weird. Just out of curiosity, can you try changing the date of one of your migration files to yesterday and run migrate? I don't really think it will help, but give it a try @AlexPelletier

Comment: so I did that and then migrated and it worked to create the table. do I have to do that for every file one by one, or does that indicate that I did something wrong to let them chain together?

Comment: What time is it at your place, and what is the time setting in your laravel application? @AlexPelletier

Comment: god dammit. Yes I did not set my laravel time, I remember just skipping over it.

Comment: I think the dates are in the future for you, so laravel might have had a problem with it... Good that it works now! Please mark the answer as accepted if it has helped you.